# How to increase brightness of screen on Android?

Tags: android, preferenceactivity, listpreference

I'm trying to develop an app which change the brightness in a PreferenceActivity but when i choose the item, the app is closed... why??
The Code

```
<ListPreference
android:key="brillo" 
android:title="Luminosidad"
android:summary="Escoge cuanto brillo quieres para jugar"
android:dialogTitle="Selecciona tono"
android:entries="@array/modobrillo"
android:entryValues="@array/codigobrillo"
/>
```

the arrays

```
<string-array name="modobrillo">
  <item>Nivel Bajo</item>
  <item>Nivel Medio</item>
  <item>Nivel Alto</item>
```

```
   <string-array name="codigobrillo">
      <item>0</item>
      <item>1</item>
     <item>2</item>
   </string-array>
```

On a Activity I do not even have code... Help!!

Comment: Any error? May be you don't have the proper code to handle the view clicks.

Comment: The arrays you referenced in `android:entries` and `android:entryValues` do not match the array resources you posted

Comment: i'am sorry i already post the new code